# How to set default profile in maven

Tags: maven

In the pom.xml, there is the following lines.

Sometimes, the maven goals include `-Dlucene7`, I'm guessing that when there is `-Dlucene7` it activates the 2nd profile and when the maven command does not have `-Dlucene7`, it activates the first profile.

```
    <profile>
        <id>lucene-3.3.0</id>

        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!lucene7</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
......

    <profile>
        <id>lucene-7.3.1</id>

        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>lucene7</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
```

If I want to set only lucene7 profile by default, can I replace the above by:

```
    <!--<profile>
        <id>lucene-3.3.0</id>

        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!lucene7</name>
            </property>
        </activation> -->
......

    <profile>
        <id>lucene-7.3.1</id>

    <!--    <activation>
            <property>
                <name>lucene7</name>
            </property>
        </activation>  -->
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
             ........
```

Or can I simply remove the profiles section and move the `dependencyManagement/dependancies` to the outer level?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to activate/deactivate it, you can just move it to the normal sections.